# How to break C-C bond in a cyclohexanone?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I cannot find a way to start this reaction. For the end, I found that a H that is attached to C with OTs group will be deprotonated forming double bond but before that I think I need to break C-C bond of ketone. Can someone help me on writing the mechanism of this reaction? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The most acidic proton in the starting material is alpha to the sulfonyl group

Comment: There is a similar reaction on [Chegg](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/underset-mathrm-dmso-stackrel-mathrm-nah-longrightarrow-q109768442) which doesn't lose the methyl group on the butyl chain: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac8Mz.png. It also has some subtle visual hints about how the ring forms.

Comment: @Waylander So alpha in this context means the carbon directly bonded to sulfur?

Comment: "I found that a H that is attached to C with OTs group will be deprotonated forming double bond". The two carbons which will form the double bond have the "right" number of hydrogen atoms attached already (zero and two), so there is no need to deprotonate there.

Comment: @Karsten  yes, the protons next to the sulfonyl group are acidic enough to be removed by NaH

Comment: As for the second part of the mechanism, learn about Grob fragmentation. Then you will know what to due with the sulfonyl anion.

Comment: Something is wrong in the product. There is a methyl group present in the starting material that should be on the 6-member ring. That methyl group incidentally does not have stereochemistry expressed, but I suspect that it is quite important when it's so close to the norbonyl system...

Comment: Yes, the methyl group should be present in the product. It was mistakenly not added to the drawing.